# Google Sheets Range Not Found How To FIX

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been trying to make a game where when a player rolls or press play. the system will generate a random number from 1-100 but will not let the player see it. After it is generated, the player will be given a few clues to the number such as (the number is from 1-10) (it is an odd number) and it is also a prime. When I was trying to create a solution button, it said [Exception: Range not found]. Here is what I coded so far:

```
function myFunction() { 
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Main")
 .getRange('E7,E7').setValue("The number is 23!")
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

The code errors out because you are calling the `.getRange()` method with `E7,E7` which is not a valid A1-type range reference. Replace that with `E7` to make it work, like this:

```
function myFunction() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('Main!E7').setValue('The number is 23!');
}
```

Comment: I gather that this is your first question at Stack Exchange. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)